# How to run a cmd with "start" using subprocess in Python

Tags: python, windows, cmd, subprocess

I am trying to start a program called drive snapshot via python script, however I cannot make it work with subprocess.

If below cmd is used directly in command line, it works just fine:

```
start pathtoprogram pathtoimage E: -vq
```

However, in python, when I am trying to use:

```
subprocess.run("start pathtoprogram pathtoimage E: -vq"
```

or

```
subprocess.checkoutput("start pathtoprogram pathtoimage E: -vq"
```

I get FileNotFound error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\mainv9_working\test2.py", line 5, in <module>
    subprocess.run("start C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/snapshot.exe C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/snapshot/C_drive.SNA E: -vq")
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 501, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 966, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 1435, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

When used without "start", it works but script doesn't continue after cmd is executed. I have found that os.system() works, but it's deprecated and vulnerable, so I would like to avoid using it.

Any help would be appreaciated.

Comment: The [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) is on Windows a Python wrapper for the Windows kernel function [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) called with or without structure [STARTUPINFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-startupinfow) depending on the used arguments to start an executable. `cmd.exe` uses also `CreateProcess` with an individually filled out `STARTUPINFO` structure.

Comment: Which properties in `STARTUPINFO` structure are set and which parameters are used on calling `CreateProcess` is determined by `cmd.exe` on the arguments of the command line, i.e. running the executable without or with command `start`. In fact there is absolutely no need to take the roundabout route to with using `subprocess.run` to call `CreateProcess` to start `cmd.exe` which should call next also `CreateProcess` to run the program *drive snapshot*. There can and should be run *drive snapshot* with `subprocess.run` or `subprocess.Popen` directly without using `cmd.exe` at all.

Comment: The execution of `cmd /?` and `start /?` in a command prompt window results in the output of the usage helps for `cmd.exe` explaining how it interprets the arguments after option `/C` (execute command line and close) or option `/K` (execute command line and keep running) and its internal command `start`. However, there is neither `cmd.exe` nor its internal command necessary because of `C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\snapshot.exe` can be run directly from within the Python script using `subprocess.run` or `subprocess.Popen`.

Comment: How the Python code using `subprocess module` to start `snapshot.exe` without using completely unnecessary `cmd.exe` at all cannot be answered without lots of more facts. Is `snapshot.exe` a Windows GUI application which opens itself a graphical window or a Windows console application? In case of being a console application, should a console window be opened by using `subprocess.Popen` with `startupinfo` with the right flags to instruct `CreateProcess`to open a console window with default settings or with settings defined in the Python script?

Comment: Should `snapshot.exe` be executed with Python script processing blocked until the executable terminated itself or should it run detached so that the Python script processing immediately continues while `snapshot.exe` is running parallel? All these facts to know determine which function of the `subprocess` module is used and which arguments are passed to the used function to call `CreateProcess` function of Windows with the correct parameters and a `STARTUPINFO` structure which results in the wanted execution behavior for `snapshot.exe`.

Comment: Please read also the Microsoft documentation about [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file). If the Python script is for usage only on Windows, specify file/folder paths with using ``\`` as directory separator and not `/` which is the directory separator on Linux/Mac. Than the Windows I/O functions do not need to correct all `/` to ``\`` in file/folder strings before passing the file/folder strings to the appropriate file system functions.

Answer (score 0):

Set the shell param to `True` when invoking the `subprocess.run()` method.

```py
subprocess.run("start pathtoprogram pathtoimage E: -vq", shell=True)
```

Answer (score -1):

### try this:

```
from subprocess import Popen as po
cmd = ['pathtoprogram', 'pathtoimage', 'E:', '-vq']
my_process = po(cmd) #start the process
my_process.wait() #wait for the process to finish
print('process has finished')
```

### or this:

```
from subprocess import Popen as po
cmd = ['pathtoprogram', 'pathtoimage', 'E:', '-vq']
my_process = po(cmd, start_new_session=True) #start the process in new session
print('python script will exit now, but the my_process will still be running')
```

Comment: It is closer to what I want to achieve. The second option requires additional enter to finish the script.

The first option's behavior is the same as in subprocess.run or checkoutput when I don't use "start" (window is stuck). If I delete my_process.wait() it's the same as the second option you've posted.